# Distinct values of two queries

Tags: mysql

I need to filter duplicates, but union is displaying duplicates.

```
For example Query-1 is displaying 5 tuples like 1,2,3,4,5.
Query-2 generating 3 tuples like 1,2,6.
Union of both the tuples displaying result 1,2,3,4,5,1,2,6.
But I want the result as 1,2,3,4,5,6.
```

Here is my controller :

```
public function product()
{
    $product = $this->input->post('keyword');
    $temp = explode(" ", $product);
    $count = count($temp);
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
    {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE SOUNDEX(`name`) LIKE CONCAT('%',SOUNDEX('$temp[$i]'),'%') UNION SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE `name` like '%$temp[$i]%'";
        $data = $this->Back_model->getby_query($query);
        $records = json_encode($data);
        echo $records;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  It is not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Using `UNION` will remove duplicates. You have to edit the question so we can understand what is duplicate.

Comment: yes. edit your question right now. #Manjhi

Comment: yeah I edited my question, if I didn't edit it clearly sorry for that. hope you understand what I want. Thank you :)

Comment: The edit is not good. You have to show duplicate rows. For example if you see tuple 1 two times this means that some of the information is different (you are using `*` which means all records and `UNION` which removes duplicates).

Comment: show the tables structures in proper manner. What are the 1,2,3,4 etc? Are those values reamin within the `id` attribute?

Comment: those are tuple's id attributes

Comment: why not just use `OR` e.g. select ... where condition1 OR condition2 no need for 2 queries

Answer (score 0):

There is no apparent reason for using 2 select queries, the second filter may be added to an existing where clause

```
   SELECT * 
   FROM `product` 
   WHERE SOUNDEX(`name`) LIKE CONCAT('%',SOUNDEX('$temp[$i]'),'%')
   AND `name` like '%$temp[$i]%'";
```

Answer (score -2):

First of all, I would probably do this in another scripting language, but if you really want to do this in MySQL, you need to use `DISTINCT`. You should query the data and put it in a temp table, and from the temp table query the `DISTINCT` values. Once you're done you can drop the temp table. For an operation this small, not sure if this is what I would do, but if you say that you have thousands of records/values that need to be filtered, than it might be worth it.

Comment: `UNION` produces a distinct result, this suggestion does not makes sense

Comment: If you read what the asker wrote, he said that it was not producing a unique result, this is what it was producing: **1,2,3,4,5,1,2,6** Marking my answer down without full reading the question and what my response was is not the appropriate action.

Comment: SELECT ... UNION [ALL | **DISTINCT**] SELECT although the word distinct is optional, the choice you have when using union is `union all` or `union distinct`, if you just use `union` distinct is still assumed. see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html so despite offering an alternative method there is no reason to assume it would solve the (as yet undocumented) problem

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I didn't think of that (I actually used this before, something similar), that is a great answer, thank you @Used_By_Already for the example also, it was an excellent refresher!

Comment: I didn't get what you told @ Used_By_Already. What I wrote the query is correct?? else please write the query :) thank you!

Comment: Updated the answer to include the suggestion from @Used_By_Already

Comment: You have misunderstood my comment. By default the word `UNION` acts `UNION DISTINCT` so by adding the word DISTINCT you have actually  achieved zero (no gain, no loss). i.e. the word "distinct" is optional, and unnecessary which is why you see it used so very rarely.